# Replace pattern for directed edges

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a list of directed edges for a graph and I want to replace all edges that match a certain pattern. The edges should be replaced by a number. It ends up in a edge weighting list for a graph. All edges that go to "window" should have the same weight. Therefore the replacement.
I tried this:

```
ReplaceList[{"a" \[DirectedEdge] "window", 
  "window" \[DirectedEdge] "door"}, 
 y_ \[DirectedEdge] x_ /; x == "window" -> 2]
```

The pattern matching does not work in this case.
The goal is to replace only edges were "window" is the receiving vertex. Is there a way to do it in similar fashion to above trial? Can the pattern matching made to work in ReplaceList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) with level specification `All`:

```
Replace[{"a" \[DirectedEdge] "window", "window" \[DirectedEdge] "door"}, 
 y_ \[DirectedEdge] x_ /; x == "window" -> 2, All]
```

or, shorter,

```
Replace[{"a" \[DirectedEdge] "window", "window" \[DirectedEdge] "door"},
   _ \[DirectedEdge] "window" ->  2, All]
```

and

```
Replace[{"a" \[DirectedEdge] "window", "window" \[DirectedEdge] "door"}, 
 DirectedEdge[_, "window"] -> 2, All]
```

to get

> ```
>  {2, "window" \[DirectedEdge] "door"}
> ```

**Note:** As commented by @Szabolcs, `DirectedEdge` may have three arguments in version 12.1. So if the input list contains tagged edges we can use the replacement rule

```
DirectedEdge[_, "window", ___] -> 2
```

Comment: `DirectedEdge` may have a 3rd argument in 12.1 (EdgeTaggedGraph)